# Change shape of a button with custom svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a website with a carousel sliders library. The thing is, each slider has a button circle-shaped with border radius and when I click one button I assign it the 'active' class, so when is active I make the button bigger. But I want to change it's shape too, to make it look like a star. I thought that putting an svg with clipPath would make the trick, but I didn't work. If anyone could tell me how to make it change it's shape, if it's any library or something, it would help me a lot.

Here's what I tried:

```html
<button>
    <svg class="star2svg">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clipStar">
                <path class="star2" id="star2" d="M325.07,30.69l80.91,163.95l180.93,26.29c18.09,2.63,25.31,24.86,12.22,37.62L468.22,386.16l30.91,180.2
                c3.09,18.02-15.82,31.76-32,23.25l-161.83-85.08l-161.83,85.08c-16.18,8.51-35.09-5.23-32-23.25l30.91-180.2L11.45,258.55
                c-13.09-12.76-5.87-34.99,12.22-37.62l180.93-26.29l80.91-163.95C293.61,14.3,316.98,14.3,325.07,30.69z"/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</button>
```

And wanted to style it this way:

```css
button {
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 0.8em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    position: relative;
    clip-path: url('#clipStar');

    .star2svg {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could swap/transition the svg path shape via css `path()` function.

For transitions/morphing you need both shapes to have the exact same number of commands.
[Css tricks: Animate SVG Path Changes in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/animate-svg-path-changes-in-css/)

Transitioning between a circle and a star could be done by:

- reducing the star path to a polygon with 10 points
- rounded corners are achieved by stroke-linecaps/stroke-linejoin properties
- the initial circle shape is created by aligning all 10 points to the center and applying a larger stroke-width: `M50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1z`

#### Example

```css
.btn {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 10vw;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnSvg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
}

.btn .btnSvgPath {
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: none;
  stroke-width: 75;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.btn:hover .btnSvgPath {
  d: path('M50,77L23.3,91l5.1-29.7l-21.6-21L36.7,36L50,9l13.3,27l29.8,4.3l-21.6,21L76.7,91L50,77z');
  stroke-width: 5;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
    <svg class="btnSvg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
        <path class="btnSvgPath" d="M50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1L50,53.1z" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
    </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: I think this solves my problem, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `svg` element needs a `viewBox` to know where to start displaying the content and where to clip it.

In this case, your `viewBox` is about `650x650`:

```css
.star2svg {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <svg class="star2svg" viewBox="0 0 650 650">
        <path d="M325.07,30.69l80.91,163.95l180.93,26.29c18.09,2.63,25.31,24.86,12.22,37.62L468.22,386.16l30.91,180.2 c3.09,18.02-15.82,31.76-32,23.25l-161.83-85.08l-161.83,85.08c-16.18,8.51-35.09-5.23-32-23.25l30.91-180.2L11.45,258.55
                c-13.09-12.76-5.87-34.99,12.22-37.62l180.93-26.29l80.91-163.95C293.61,14.3,316.98,14.3,325.07,30.69z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Well, I can display it inside the button now, but I want the button to take the shape of the svg

Comment: @GLPG35 I added two solutions to this problem

Comment: The reason I want my button to take the shape of the svg is because my button has the shape of a circle and I want to convert it to a star only when is active, so I can make an animation.